# Implementation of Shared Storage Drive Between Ubuntu And Win10?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, storage

***Background***: I've recently been rebuilding my super machine. I am also new to linux-based systems, and hope to use them to replace Windows for general computing/dev. Windows will still be used for games.

***Setup***: Machine has 3 drives inside(SSD, HDD, Hybrid). All three drives are currently NTFS format. SSD has a freshly installed copy of Win10. I was going to install Ubuntu on the HDD. The plan after that, would be to have the hybrid drive shared somehow.

***Asking***: I'd like to setup the hybrid drive to be the storage drive for BOTH OSes. The OS drives should have nothing except drivers and OS files. All other files period should not be on the hybrid drive. When in Ubuntu, I shouldn't be aware of the files that I've saved/installed to it from Windows. From Windows, I shouldn't be aware of files on the drive I've saved/installed from Ubuntu. Is this possible or am I dreaming big?

Thanks in advance for any replies and criticism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing Ubuntu, choose to partition the disks manually and set up your /home directory to be on an EXT4 partition on the hybrid drive. The Windows partition on the hybrid drive needs to NTFS formatted and needs to be D:\users or whatever drive letter you would like to assign.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much! Looking forward to trying to implement this later today! thank you. I will report how it goes. Is it possible to setup the 2 partitions on the hybrid in Windows before installing Ubuntu? Right now, the Hybrid is 1 NTFS partition of the entire available space.

Comment: In Windows, reduce the size of the NTFS partition to take up just half of the drive. I don't have very much experience with windows, so that's all I can tell you. When are ready to install Ubuntu, just create an EXT4 partition that will fill up the remaining half of the hybrid drive and set the mount point for the EXT4 partition as your /home directory. 
I hope this works and I'm glad to help!

Comment: If this doesn't work, you just hold tight and I'll test stuff out in a virtual machine

Comment: Hi, I'm attempting these now

Comment: So far this is perfect. Half the drive partitioned NTFS, windows shows my drive letter and name with only half the available storage. I'm going to go install Ubuntu now and partition the free space as EXT4 and mount it @ /home. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I was able to pull off the exact configuration I wanted! Looks good. I do have some minor BIOs problem with boot order and such now but it isn't a critical issue. The system is usable.  Thanks alot.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad to help

Comment: I actually solve my boot issue as well! In my case, I shouldn't partition GRUB to it's own partition. It should install on same partition as Ubuntu OS. Both OS now on their own drive, sharing the hybrid for storage. GRUB booter asks me which OS I want on boot. It is very seamless! Also, side note, compile times on Linux are MUCH faster than my Win10 machine.

Comment: Yeah. I'm glad you were able to figure it out. I forgot the part about telling it where to install the boot loader, but I had a feeling you'd figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 partitions on the Hybrid drive.
One NTFS for Windows `D:\users`, Linux can mount and read/write it
Another one EXT4 for the `/home` of Ubuntu, Windows cannot read it (not natively)

Comment: This is a good suggestion, I'll try it out. Thanks! Quick question, could I create a EXT4 partition in windows before installing Ubuntu? I prefer Disk Management program.

Comment: I have also just realized a typo in my post. Neither OS should be able to see saved/installed things from the other OS. But, I feel that the method you've given here would suffice anyway. Still going to try it.